# Is it ok to down vote an answer to a poorly written question?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, down-votes

I recently came across a post that basically asked "How do I do X?".  No research effort, code, or any other details provided.  Myself and a few others commented for more information.  A few minutes later someone answered the question with code.

I down voted the answer and commented because I feel like answering a question like this only encourages people to ask these types of poorly written, undetailed questions.

Am I wrong for down voting the answer?

Comment: Did you downvote the question?  If not, it seems unfair to single out the poster who put in more effort of the two.

Comment: Yes, I downvoted the question.